# Rebroadcasting RTP over TCP into RTP over UDP

Tags: java, logic

I've been scratching my head for over a week and I am sure it's just some simple logic problem that I am overlooking... I really can't think anymore since I've been staring at my code for so long that I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can see where the issue is located at and help me fix it.

I have a bin file from wireshark that contains an RTP session over TCP, the end goal is for me to resend it over UDP. The original packet sizes are 8192 bytes, some are less than that (doesn't matter for the scope of this question, buffering packets, etc). Those 8kb packets are a part of a complete frame that spans accross multiple packets. After I collect a complete frame (read from the file, reconstruct the frame by stripping out RTP and NAL headers, then saving into a byte[]), I then will slice these up into 1400 byte chunks.

1. Slice into 1400 byte chunks
2. Reconstruct NAL header for each chunk
3. Create a new RTP header
4. put everything together and send it out via DatagramPacket

The issue here is that the last packet of the complete frame seem to be missing some bytes (I compared my messages with the one from the original bin file). What is my code doing that I'm not seeing?

```
private LinkedList<byte[]> fragmentVideoData(int newSize) {
    LinkedList<byte[]> videoFragments = new LinkedList();
    byte firstByte, secondByte, startByte, endByte;
    /*
        NAL header being reconstructed.
    */
    int videoSize = videoData.length - 1;
    int pos = 1;
    byte[] fragment = null;
    if(videoSize > newSize) {
        while(videoSize > 0) {
            fragment = new byte[(videoSize < newSize) ? videoSize : newSize];
            ByteBuffer fragmentBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(fragment);
            fragmentBuf.put(firstByte);
            if(videoFragments.isEmpty()) {
                fragmentBuf.put(startByte);
            }
            else if(videoSize < newSize) {
                fragmentBuf.put(endByte);
            }
            else if(videoSize > newSize) {
                fragmentBuf.put(secondByte);
            }
            fragmentBuf.put(videoData, pos, ((videoSize < newSize) ? videoSize : newSize) - 2);
            videoFragments.add(fragment);
            videoSize -= newSize - 2;
            pos += newSize - 2;
            fragmentBuf.clear();
        }
    }
    else {
        fragment = new byte[videoSize + 1];
        ByteBuffer fragmentBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(fragment);
        fragmentBuf.put(videoData);
        videoFragments.add(fragment);
    }
    return videoFragments;
}
```

Comment: Loop is going 2 by 2 bytes, have you try with 1 by 1 like ```fragmentBuf.put(videoData, pos, ((videoSize < newSize) ? videoSize : newSize) - 1);``` further lines should also changed to -1